# Numbering rows and columns in a grid/board

Tags: python, grid, enumerate

I am running a function which will generate a board with empty squares, represented by ' . ' and the player will be represented by a '0'.

I want to number the rows and columns to represent a coordinate that the user can easily enter when prompt too. This is the end result I had in mind:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 . . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . . 
2 . . . . . . . . 
3 . . . . . . . . 
4 . . . . . . . . 
5 . . . . . . . . 
6 . . . . . . . . 
7 . . . . . . . .
```

I think there's an enumerate function that could help with this, I just need help trying to implement it.

For reference, here's the function used to generate the grid:

```
def drawgrid(win,lose,counter,coordinate):
    for i in range(-1+(coordinate[0])):
            print(" . "*8)
    print(" . "*((coordinate[1])-1),counter," . "*(7-coordinate[1]))
    for i in range(8-coordinate[0]):
        print(" . "*8)
```

Comment: Can you show your code? I assume your using an array, would using the indices for each space work?

Comment: Currently generating the grid using a for loop that will print the spaces until the line before the player. The code will then print a specific line for the player counter to place it properly. It will then work out the remaining blank lines needed to redraw the grid. I'll edit the post to include the function used for generation.

Comment: first create 2-dimensional list to keep board information - ie. `board = [ [".", "."],  [".", "."] ]` - and then you can think about `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way to make a 'board' and then print out.

```
w,h = 8,8

board =[['.' for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
print ' ',
for i in range(w):
    print i,
print ''
for i in range(h):
    print i,
    for j in range(w):
        print board[i][j],
    print ''
```

Results

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 . . . . . . . . 
1 . . . . . . . . 
2 . . . . . . . . 
3 . . . . . . . . 
4 . . . . . . . . 
5 . . . . . . . . 
6 . . . . . . . . 
7 . . . . . . . . 
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a matrix. Do you want the labels to be visible to the player, or just accessible by the program?

Here's a little demo program that does both

```
class Cell:
    """
    :param x: x-axis location
    :param y: y-axis location
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.visual = "."

    def __str__(self):
        return self.visual

class Board:

    def __init__(self, x=10, y=10, show_labels=False):
        """
        :param x: How many columns the board uses
        :param y: How many rows the board uses
        :param show_labels: Display labels to the player
        """

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.show_labels = show_labels
        self.board = {}

        self.generate_board()

    def generate_board(self):
        for y in range(0, self.y):

            # Add the key X to the board dictionary
            self.board[y] = []   

            for x in range(0, self.x):
                # Make a cell @ the current x, y and add it to the board
                cell = Cell(x, y)
                self.board[y].append(cell)

    def show_board(self):

        for key, cells in self.board.iteritems():

            # Add the X Labels
            if self.show_labels:
                if key == 0:
                    x_label = []
                    for cell in self.board[key]:
                        x_label.append(str(cell.x + 1))
                    print "".join(x_label)

            row = []
            for cell in cells:
                row.append(str(cell))

            # Add the Y labels
            if self.show_labels:
                row.append(str(cell.y + 1))

            print "".join(row)

    def set_player(self, x, y):
        self.board[y][x].visual = "0"

b = Board(5, 5, True)
b.set_player(2, 2)
b.show_board()
```

Output for 5x5

```
12345
.....1
.....2
..0..3
.....4
.....5
```

Output for 10x8

```
12345678910
..........1
..........2
..0.......3
..........4
..........5
..........6
..........7
..........8
```